# Large Table Update Best Practice

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two table updates to run on large tables. I am changing the data types in both cases.

Table 1 has 2 million rows and requires me to drop the primary key constraint and re-add it.
Table 2 has 1 billion rows and has no constraints.

What do I need to take into consideration in doing these updates? Will the transaction log be written to for each of these transactions?

Here's my code, is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
-- 2 MILLION ROWS IN TableX -----------------------------------------------
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableX]
DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_TableX] -- Clustered Primary Key Constraint

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableX]
ALTER COLUMN [SomeColumn] CHAR(4) NOT NULL; -- WAS INT

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableX]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_TableX]
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [BusinessDate] ASC, [CustomerID] ASC )


-- 1 BILLION ROWS IN TableZ -----------------------------------------------
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableZ
ALTER COLUMN SomeColumn INT NOT NULL -- WAS CHAR(7)
```

Comment: What is the current definition of those columns?

Comment: TableX is going from INT to CHAR(4). TableZ is going from CHAR(7) to INT

Comment: T-log will be written to, yes. Switching to simple recovery obviously speeds it up, but might be risky. Also might be quicker and easier to insert into a new table, drop old and rename. If you need concurrent modification while doing that, setup triggers.

Comment: I don't think inserting it into a new table is a viable option with 1b rows. I'm thinking of dropping the indexes, running the update, re-adding the indexes. Alternatively, I guess I can script it to update in chunks to preserve the tlog. Just was hoping there was a better option.